# autohotkey not able to get Bing Desktop control

Tags: autohotkey

The Bing Desktop has a Win + Y hotkey to toggle the display of itself. But I want to bring it foreground with my Win + I hotkey.

I met with a problem that I can't set focus to the search box with *ControlFocus, Edit1* where *Edit1* is the ClassNN reported by Window Spy.

The script is posted here:

```
#i::
  IfWinExist, ahk_exe BingDesktop.exe
  {
    IfWinNotExist, ahk_class BingToolBand
    {
      Send #y
      Return
    }
    WinWait, ahk_class BingToolBand
    WinActivate
    WinWaitActive
    ControlFocus, Edit1
    Return
  }

  Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\BingDesktop\BingDesktop.exe"
Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the *ahk_class BingToolBand* is not the top windowtitle of Bing Desktop.
I should have used *必应Bing 缤纷桌面* instead.

Comment: Can't say I would have ever guessed the control name!